# How do I make my http request proxy in c#?

Tags: c#, proxy

When I use the code below I get this error: The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme.

How would I change this code around to make it proxyed?

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://website.com/index.php?");
        var myproxy = new WebProxy("https:/website.com/index.php?");

        request.Proxy = myproxy;
        string postData = "Secret=" +textBox1.text;
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

        string read = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();


        response.Close();
```

Comment: the scheme supported is http.

Comment: try setting the proxy of the HttpWebRequest by creating a webproxy() and calling proxy.GetProxy(new Uri("https://website.com/index.php?"));

Comment: can you show me an example of how you would edit my code to make it work?